# Xamarin Maps Custom Pins iOS

Tags: c#, ios, xamarin, maps, renderer

i have an application where i load specific data from an server via Json. In my case there are about 12 entries. Based on the entrie, the should be diffrent Pin images on the map. This is my code:

```
async private void GetWoodWork()
        {
.......
.......
            if(result != null)
            {
                List<ObjectData> objectDatas = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<ObjectData>>(result);
                foreach (ObjectData data in objectDatas)
                {
                    string imageName;
                    string type;
                    switch(data.objectTyp)
                    {
                        case "0":
                            imageName = "fallenTree.png";
                            type = "Umgefallener Baum";
                            break;
                        case "1":
                            imageName = "illRubbish.png";
                            type = "Illegale Müllentsorgung";
                            break;
                        case "2":
                            imageName = "rubbishFull.png";
                            type = "Mülleimer voll";
                            break;
                        case "3":
                            imageName = "handsaw.png";
                            type = "Waldarbeiten";
                            break;
                        default:
                            imageName = "questionMark.png";
                            type = "Sonstiges";
                            break;
                    }

                    Position position = new Position(double.Parse(data.latitude, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture), double.Parse(data.longitude, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture));
                    var pin = gps.AddPinToMap(type, position, imageName, LocationMap, data.objectTyp);
                    //customPins.Add(pin);
                    LocationMap.CustomPins = new List<CustomPin> { pin };
                    LocationMap.Pins.Add(pin);
                }
                LocationMap.CustomPins = customPins;
            }
        }
```

This Functions worked fine. And every Pin get the data he should. As MapRender in iOS i have the following code

```
protected override MKAnnotationView GetViewForAnnotation(MKMapView mapView, IMKAnnotation annotation)
        {
            MKAnnotationView annotationView = null;

            if (annotation is MKUserLocation)
                return null;

            customPins = formsMap.CustomPins;
            CustomPin customPin = customPins[0];
            if(customPins != null)
            {
                    annotationView = mapView.DequeueReusableAnnotation(customPin.Name);
                    if (annotationView == null)
                    {
                        annotationView = new CustomMKAnnotationView(annotation, customPin.Name);                   
                        annotationView.Image = UIImage.FromFile(customPin.ImageName);
                        annotationView.CalloutOffset = new CGPoint(0, 0);
                        annotationView.LeftCalloutAccessoryView = new UIImageView(UIImage.FromFile(customPin.ImageName));
                        annotationView.RightCalloutAccessoryView = UIButton.FromType(UIButtonType.DetailDisclosure);
                        ((CustomMKAnnotationView)annotationView).Name = customPin.Name;
                        ((CustomMKAnnotationView)annotationView).Url = customPin.Url;
                    }
                    annotationView.CanShowCallout = true;                    
            }
```

If i set a breakpoint in the `GetViewForAnnotation` at `annotationView.Image = UIImage.FromFile(customPin.ImageName)`i could see that i get the right informations there. But if the map is loaded all Pins have the same image. But they should have diffrent Images.

I have no idea and need help. Thanks in advance!

Comment: You seem to always use the first element from your `customPins` array. The data you need (image etc) should be associated with your `MKAnnotation` subclass. In `GetViewForAnnotation` you cast the supplied annotation to your subclass type and access the properties.

Comment: @Paulw11 thats right. Before i call the function `GetWoodWork` i add the acutal Position to my map. This works fine and the pin is shown with correct image. After that i call `GetWoodWork`. In this method i also tried to fill an List with all pins after that i set that list to my map. Then in the `GetViewForAnnotation` i start a foreach through the list. There i can see the correct images are set to the annotation, but if the map is loaded all pins have the same image.

Comment: But you say this: `CustomPin customPin = customPins[0];` - you are always using the first pin.  You need to use the annotation that was passed to the function. You should not need to refer to your `CustomPins` array at all when in that function.